# How do I use the Canvas to draw a smaller, but same shape inside another whilst maintaining a constant border thickness?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, png, sharp

[image]

I want to to take any shape, create a smaller version of it, and then use a negative mask to create a new shape that is like an outline of the first object, but with a **constant** thickness border. To my understanding, this is generally not possible without distorting the smaller image slightly (e.g. changing it's aspect ratio). So I'm ok if the solution creates some distortion of the smaller image.

I also know how to create a negative mask:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out'
```

Don’t worry about giving me the code for drawing these shapes on the canvas. I have code that does that fine. The problem I’m finding is that the border thickness is not constant because I need to distort the smaller shape to make it so. At the moment I haven’t distorted it and don’t know how.

One approach I thought of might be to move along the outer edge of the large image, and for each point, draw a corresponding point some constant distance inwards, which will be on the edge of the smaller image. In effect tracing the smaller image as you go around the larger one. But I don’t know how to sure the angle is correct. Do I have to use some radius of curvature?

Whether it's a some kind of mathematical solution, algorithm or a pointer to a library that I can use I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A while ago I did something "similar" to get the outline of an shape/image, hopefully that inspires to try something: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvasOutline.html

Comment: ... and for the record you are asking multiple questions: `take any shape, create a smaller version of it, and then use a negative mask to create a new shape` have you attempted to solve any part of this? Some code of what you tried is expected...

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes I’ve mentioned I’ve done the trivial attempts but thought not to share that code since it’s very basic and doesn’t solve my problem. I think a fundamentally different approach is needed because the aspect ratio needs to be changed in a general way for any shape. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Share the code of those trivial attempts it helps others better understand what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `destination-out` to cut out a piece at a time in a temporary canvas to later combine them in the "main" canvas, it's a small code at the end ...

the image I'm starting with is a sunflower:

[image]

I thought that would be a good start because of all the odd shape edges

```js
var s = 10 // thickness scale

var img = new Image;
img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/eKKoWVT.png"

var canvas = document.getElementById('c')
var t_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
t_canvas.width = canvas.width
t_canvas.height = canvas.height

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var t_ctx = t_canvas.getContext('2d')

function draw() {
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i += Math.PI / 64) {
    t_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    t_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400);
    t_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    t_ctx.drawImage(img, Math.sin(i) * s, Math.cos(i) * s, 400, 400);
    ctx.drawImage(t_canvas, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

---

Here is a "slow motion" process showing how the inline drawing is  extracted from the big image

```js
var s = 50 // thickness scale
var i = 0

var img = new Image;
img.onload = draw
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/eKKoWVT.png"

var canvas = document.getElementById('c')
var t_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
t_canvas.width = canvas.width
t_canvas.height = canvas.height

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var t_ctx = t_canvas.getContext('2d')

function draw() {
  t_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  t_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  t_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  t_ctx.drawImage(img, Math.sin(i) * s, Math.cos(i) * s, 400, 400);
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
  ctx.drawImage(t_canvas, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  
  ctx.moveTo(200 + Math.sin(i) * 9, 200 + Math.cos(i) * 9)
  ctx.lineTo(200 + Math.sin(i) * s, 200 + Math.cos(i) * s)
  ctx.stroke()

  i += Math.PI / 64
  if (i < 8)
    setTimeout(draw, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.

Do you know there are small coloured pixel artifacts being added to the edge of the final image?

Comment: @Sol most likely those small artifacts exist in the original too and overlapping images is making them more noticeable ... Don't forget to upvote the answer if it was helpful and accept it if it answers your question

Comment: Yes I agree. In that case it's fine and I'll mark it as accepted. What an elegant solution! Thanks!